# Java Program Not Outputting Correctly - VectorStack

Tags: java, debugging

I'm creating a test driver for a program I'm working on and for some reason, my remove method isn't working properly. I can't find the problem. Whenever I remove something, it outputs true correctly. However, whenever I remove something not within my vectorstack it errors out, badly. Can anyone take a look at it and see whats up? I tried to put something that would determine if the value was found or not (similar to the contains method) but I couldn't figure that one out either.

Here's everything you'll need to run it:

https://pastebin.com/6YD6RvsB this is the test driver.

```
System.out.println("Now we removin' -4 (should return false): " + s.remove(14));
```

This is the line that errors out.
https://pastebin.com/jQWZS1KA this is VectorStack.

https://pastebin.com/8Hh5nK3C here is StackSort.

```
public boolean remove(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
       return false;
    boolean found = false;

    findStackLocation(obj);
    store.pop();
    size--;
    found = true;

    emptyTempStack();
    return found;
}
```

this is the remove method thats erroring out.

```
    public boolean contains(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
       return false;
    boolean found = false;

    findStackLocation(obj);

    while (!found && !store.empty() && store.peek().compareTo(obj) == 0) {
        if (store.peek().equals(obj))
        found = true;
        else
        temp.push(store.pop());

        emptyTempStack();  
    }
     return found;
}
```

This is the contains method to compare it to. 
https://pastebin.com/6SyHhqkm and here is stack.

Thanks for any help you guys can give me!

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at VectorStack.pop(VectorStack.java:51)
at StackSort.remove(StackSort.java:60)
at StackDriver.main(StackDriver.java:26)
```

Comment: *it errors out, badly* - please post your stacktrace

Comment: The stack trace would be very helpful.  Are you ever setting store to null? If so, that could be causing a NullPointerException. You would need to check  store == null in your while loop as well. Also check the return of store.peek and verify that if it returns null, you're checking for it in your while condition.

Comment: I added a stack trace to help out.

Comment: So basically to sum it up, it should output a false in my test driver whenever i try to remove a value that isn't there. However, it errors out.